# Is "cause" instead of "because" becoming Standard English?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context, word-usage

Nowadays, I'm seeing a drastic increase in usage of *cause* in place of *because*, especially in written English. People are in such a hurry, that a statement like below passes off like Standard English:

> It rains *cause* clouds form in the sky, and that happens *cause* of water vapor, and vapor forms *cause* of trees and forests.

Is this particular use of *cause* in place of *because* in danger of getting into the Standard English Dictionary? Do you think it is correct?

Comment: Where did you find that phrase ? It does not looks like standard English at all.

Comment: That is horrid English and whoever wrote it should be sent back to remedial English classes.

Comment: No--only in informal writing situations, like personal letters, texting, and Facebook conversations. That being said, I think it will happen eventually: The conjunction *for* began in OE as part of the phrase *for þy*, which in ME became *for that*, and in EMoDE just *for*. The word *because* has already been truncated from the ME phrase *by cause that*, so there's no reason to expect it not to follow the same path as *for*, becoming a monosyllabic conjunction.

Comment: I should also mention that at least one of Shakespeare's plays uses *'cause*, though I can't remember which; it's one of the co-written plays.

Comment: What others said. One might hear it being used in informal speech/writing, but not any any kind of speech writing where you'd want to not look uneducated. If it did show up in a dictionary, it would most likely be labeled as informal.

Comment: Definition of ***'cause***  in English:
(conjunction)

 - informal
(short for because.) (ODO) http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/%E2%80%99cause?q=%27cause

Comment: @Anonym - I don't know why people insist on using Shakespeare as _the_ formal standard of English. He was writing 400 years ago, half in poetry, made up half his words, slurred and contracted like a sailor, used singular 'they' and prepositions at the ends of sentences, and probably threw a shoe at a kitten.

Comment: Yes, it's informal but the important thing there is the apostrophe... it's showing the fact that the word has been shortened.

Comment: Definition of ***cos***  - conjunction
(British informal)
Short for because. (ODO) 
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cos?q=%27cos#cos-3

Comment: The Standard English Dictionary?  Is that figurative?

Comment: @Mitch I don't think they do--but, if use by influential writers legitimizes a word at all, then we can find none better than Shakespeare.

Comment: 'Cause, @Mitch, he did more to **form** modern English than any other individual we know of. English is something like a popularity contest with the words as contestants, and Shakespeare's words won the popularity contest so **decisively** that we still use them. Cruelty against animals might become more popular if someone demonstrated that he actually did throw a shoe at a kitten ;-)

Comment: @snailboat Yeah. Its a figurative, imaginative and ephemeral dictionary residing in the unconscious psyche of the English speaking masses.

Comment: I would say that `'cause` is as legitimate as, say, `what're`, but the apostrophe must be included when written.

Comment: You ask "*Is it in danger of getting into the Standard English Dictionary?"* Too late; it's already in the OED. Although it says "now only *dial.*, or *vulgar.*"

Comment: @Mitch - Besides, don't blame Shakespeare, blame the authors who actually wrote the stuff he takes credit for.  (If any angry mobs are looking for me, I'll be in the next county.)

Comment: @Mitch Of course Shakespeare used prepositions at the ends of sentences.  How could he have followed a (so-called) rule that [didn't exist](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/101545/13287) [when he was alive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/137218/13287)

Comment: @Mitch Shakespeare used _singular they_? My appreciation of him has further increased.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, I remember the 'singular they' thing vaguely from hearsay. [But... someone did the needful](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/002748.html).

Comment: ... I'm glad he used present-day logical linguistic devices. A man ahead of the game.

Comment: Shakespeare was writing for the common folk of his day, and used vernacular extensively. His plays were the Elizabethan equivalent of our soap operas.

Comment: @Josh61: ODO included `cos`? Without even the apostrophe? I just died a little.

Comment: @Barmar That is why he has so much fame. And lord Byron... Well, that's a whole different story, isn't it?

Comment: I wanna know when I can shorten it to `cuz`. Far more efficient, just as effective at communicating intent. Why'd ya doit? Cuz i could.

Comment: '[I]n danger of getting into the Standard English Dictionary [assume 'lexis']' is overly prejudicial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause can be said in different forms, such as "the cause of the forming of clouds". In your case, cause is used like an abbreviation, which is 'cause. So, 'cause is technically an abbreviation.

Hope this answers your question :)

Comment: But some abbreviations are standard, others aren't. This does not address the question (as it is presented here and now).