# Do Americans still use 'because' or is it always 'cos'?

Tags: differences, american-english, vocabulary

Do Americans still use the word 'because' or is it only used as ''cause' or 'cos'?

Comment: Don't forget *coz*... So, you never hear American speakers say *“because”* interesting, 'cos I know a few  Brits who would disagree with you there.

Comment: Have a look at ngram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=because%2Ccos%2Ccoz%2Ccause&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cbecause%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbecause%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBecause%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccos%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcos%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCos%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCOS%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCOs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccoz%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcoz%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCoz%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCOz%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCOZ%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccause%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcause%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCause%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Thanks k1eran! Hadn't came across that site before. Very useful

Comment: Yes, we still say "because".

Comment: I wouldn't write "cos", because I pronounce it as "cuzz" (rhyming with "buzz").

Comment: I'm sure even young people say 'because' much of the time.  "I won't mow the lawn because it will just grow back again" etc....especially when emphasizing disagreement... perhaps "i went back upstairs cuzz I forgot my keys" might be said frequently but I think I hear most adults and some kids throw in a b there too.

Comment: @k1eran Ngrams is utterly unreliable for casual speech, and slang. But it's a great tool for formal language, and searching for first instances in print. However, if you want to know where *yall* or *y'all* is more commonly heard, you need to ask someone who lives in the US and has actually conducted a study ditto for 'cause, 'cos, and 'coz.

Comment: Texting will be the death of English, but we aren't there yet.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247619/is-cause-instead-of-because-becoming-standard-english

Answer (score 2):

> ***[Cos,](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/because-because-of-and-cos-cos-of)***  a short form of because, is pronounced /kəz/ or /kɒz/ and can also be spelt ’cause.
>
> - It can be used instead of because (and cos of instead of because of). ***We often use it in speaking, emails and text messages, especially in informal situations:***

A:

> Why are you and Adam not talking to each other?

B:

> Cos he’s always saying nasty things about me.

and

> I don’t eat meat cos I love animals.
>
> They cancelled the trip cos of the snow.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Or also /kʌz/ in stressed position. But it's usually weak.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, "cause" and "cos" are *verbal shortcut*, not formal abbreviations or anything like that. That means you'll never see them in written English (unless you're quoting something someone said aloud).

But yes, Americans still say "because", depending probably on how formal they are speaking, the intended audience, and where in the sentence the word appears.

[Here is an ngram for because vs cause vs cos vs cuz](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=because%2Ccos%2Ccoz%2Ccause&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cbecause%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbecause%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBecause%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccos%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcos%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCos%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCOS%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCOs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccoz%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcoz%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCoz%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCOz%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCOZ%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccause%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcause%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCause%3B%2Cc0), as posted in comments by k1eran. My personal opinion is that this graph isn't particularly useful, those instances of "cause" are probably the literal word, not the verbal shortcut.

Comment: I also tried: "because of,cos of,coz of,cause of" ngram but it didn't look much different. And yes fully agreed with comments from you and @Mari-LouA regarding ngram's limitations for slang/spoken word.